# Issue with JQuery Image Bubbles in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to implement Jquery Image Bubbles as shown here:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagebubbles.htm

However Im receiving a JavaScript error in my Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/hbMzV/

It was determined that loading the JavaScript file from the dynamicdrive Demo Page into the Fiddle would not function.  Copying the JavaScript directly did function.

Comment: I get no errors in FF11. Could you post the error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was receiving an error that the `imgbubbles` method does not exist. This means the resource wasn't being loaded into the fiddle. The solution was simple.

Rather than trying to load the file into your page from the dynamicdrive domain, copy it to your project folder and load it from there. In your fiddle, I pulled the actual source for the plugin into the JavaScript panel, which resolved the issue of the missing method.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hbMzV/13/ (Tested in IE 7 to 10)

Comment: how did you determine that imgbubbles didn't exist? Safari JavaScript Debugger?

Comment: @Paul From within IE hit F12. This opens the [F12 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx). From there you have access to a console that will contain errors and warnings.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hbMzV/16/ Now the z-index returns to normal after it animates back down to normal size, if mouseout was called before the animation was complete, one of the other images showed through.

Answer (score 0):

JSLint says to throw in some semi-colons, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('ul#orbs').imgbubbles({factor:3.15, speed:1500});
});
```

Looks like it works even without them though.